# what arguments does the sendTransaction function take?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, web3js, cpp-ethereum

I have set up my private blockchain using geth and am using web3 to call different methods. I have successfully created new accounts from the web browser and can view all addresses and the balances. Next i am trying to send some ether from one account to the other.

In javascript I have

```
acc1 = web3.eth.accounts[0];  
acc2 = web3.eth.accounts[1];   
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: acc1, to: acc2, Value: 1})
```

I encounter an error as follows 
Error: invalid argument 0: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data

Has anyone faced this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to like the big "V" because it's case-sensitive.

Here's a reference to the whole list:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. I thought it was referring to the first argument and not the third. When working with the geth node in the terminal it used to accept the upper case. But in this case it did not. Thanks Again.